# i dont understand why i keep getting a network error from axios,advice?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I'm working on a problem that I need to connect my frontend to my backend react and spring boot respectively. all I get is "network error" as information from the call stack. It's weird because my controller allows for cross-origin. I made this work on another project but maybe I forgot a bean.

my controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000","http://localhost:3001"})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/authentification")
public class AuthentificationController {
    @Autowired
    AuthentificationServices authentificationServices;
@Autowired
    JasyptConfig jasyptConfig;
    @Autowired
    EmailService emailService;
    @GetMapping
...
    @GetMapping("/getBySighnIn/{email}/{password}")
    public Employee getauthentificationByEmailPassword(@PathVariable String email, @PathVariable String password){
        ArrayList<Authentification> authentifications=authentificationServices.getauthentification();
        try {

          for(int i=0;i<authentifications.size();i++){
              if(email.equals(authentifications.get(i).getEmployee().getEmail())
                      &&password.equals(jasyptConfig.encryptor().decrypt(authentifications.get(i).getPassword()))){

                  Employee employee=authentifications.get(i).getEmployee();
                  employee.setEmail(jasyptConfig.encryptor().decrypt(employee.getEmail()));
                  employee.setPhoneNumber(jasyptConfig.encryptor().decrypt(employee.getPhoneNumber()));
                  employee.setAddress(jasyptConfig.encryptor().decrypt(employee.getAddress()));
                    //go back too
                  return employee;
              }
          }
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e){
            return null;
        }
        return null;

    }
  
}
```

my react page

```
import React, {Component,Fragment} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import JSOG from 'jsog';
class SighnIn extends Component {

         constructor(props)
          {
              super(props);
              this.state = {
                email:"",
                password: "",
                message:"",
                employee:{}
              }
              this.sighnUp=this.sighnUp.bind(this);
              this.forgot=this.forgot.bind(this);
        
          }
        sighnUp=async ()=>{
            let obj;
            let email=this.state.email;
            let password=this.state.password;
            
            await axios.get(
                'http://localhost:8080/authentification/getBySighnIn/'+email+'/'+password)
                   .then(res => {
                    console.log("hi");
                   obj = JSOG.stringify(res.data);
                   console.log("hi");  
                   this.setState({employee:obj});
                    this.props.sighnIn(obj);


                 }).catch(
                 function (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                });

              
              

        }
      forgot=()=>{
        this.props.hasForgot();
       } 
      render()
      {
  
        return(
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <form onSubmit={this.sighnUp}>
                            
                                <div>
                                    <label htmlFor="email">email:</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="email" onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({email:e.target.value})}} value={this.state.email} />                       
                                </div>
                                  <div>
                                        <label htmlFor="password">password:</label>
                                     <input type="text" id="password" onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({password:e.target.value})}} value={this.state.password} />
                                    </div>
                                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                            </form></div>
                            <div>
                                <button onClick={this.forgot}>forgot password</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>);
       
    
    
      }
    
  }
  
  // Exporting the component
  export default SighnIn;
```

app.properties

```
##for crud application
# DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/divinapopina?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=****
## dont know what this one does
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
# Hibernate
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE



##for log in
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

#gmail
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=realtyking66@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=****
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.protocol=smtp
spring.mail.test-connection=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "divinapopinaemployeeportal",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "jsog": "^1.0.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^9.1.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy":"http://localhost:3000"
}
```

Comment: You can get more detail out of the Axios error by using `console.error(error.response?.data, error.toJSON())`. You can also see all the request and response details in your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel. What do you see from applying these debugging techniques?

Comment: Also, passing credentials not only via GET request but in the actual URL path is terrible from an application security perspective. If you want to sign in, use a POST request and pass the credentials in the request body

Comment: A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because of invalid or missing response headers of the request or the associated preflight request .
To fix this issue, ensure the response to the CORS request and/or the associated preflight request are not missing headers and use valid header values.
Note that if an opaque response is sufficient, the request's mode can be set to no-cors to fetch the resource with CORS disabled; that way CORS headers are not required but the response content is inaccessible (opaque).